# How do I use the Twilio API to send a WhatsApp message to my phone when a sensor is triggered through a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, twilio, sensors

I am using a Raspberry Pi in a project, and want to use the Twilio API to send a message to my phone through WhatsApp when a sensor is triggered. Is there a way to do this?

I tried it through SMS texting but realized I want it to work overseas (don’t want it to charge me money overseas)

Comment: It's certainly possible to achieve what you're looking to do, but in order to provide a more accurate and helpful answer, it would be great if you could add more details on what you've tried so far, and any specific issues you're encountering. Adding code snippets, error messages, and a clear explanation of your expected outcome can also help the community to understand your problem better and offer targeted assistance. Please edit your question with this additional context, and I'll be happy to help further!

Answer (score 0):

Twilio messaging API also supports sending WhatsApp messages. You need to enable a phone number for WhatsApp messaging and use it to send messages to another WhatsApp number.

https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/tutorial